# QML: how to use Date function

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to develop my first `QML` application. I have a control that returns an integer which is supposed to be a year. I would like to check if this value is a leap year.

The `QDate` class has a `isLeapYear()` static method but I wonder how I can use it from within a QML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below using Javascript/QML should work, assuming you are on Qt5:

```
// MyItem.qml
Item {
function isLeap(hyear) {
    return ((hyear % 100 != 0) && (hyear % 4 == 0)) || (hyear % 400 == 0);
  }
}
```

If you want to get the value and use in C++, you need to type cast the values with the methods outlined in

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html

Comment: Thanks! This does work and I realised I can use the `Date` object as well to solve this particular problem. Would be great though to use Qt C++ classes from QML as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Qt documentation about integrating C++ with QML files. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html) you have examples and how to do that from official Qt Website. I think that you could send `signal` from `QML` and connect it to `slot` which call `isLeapYear()`

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I need to look into how to use C++ classes with QML.